# dependency error while running windowsfeature

Tags: windows, manifest, puppet, windows-server-2012-r2, puppet-enterprise

This is how my manifest looks like:

```
class dotNetCore
{
  notify { 'Installing NET-Framework-Core': }
  windowsfeature { 'NET-Framework-Core': }
  notify { 'Finished Installing NET-Framework-Core': }
}
class installIIS{
  require dotNetCore
  notify { 'Installing IIS': }
  windowsfeature { 'IIS':
    feature_name => [
      'Web-Server',
      'Web-WebServer',
      'Web-Asp-Net45',
      'Web-ISAPI-Ext',
      'Web-ISAPI-Filter',
      'NET-Framework-45-ASPNET',
      'WAS-NET-Environment',
      'Web-Http-Redirect',
      'Web-Filtering',
      'Web-Mgmt-Console',
      'Web-Mgmt-Tools'
    ]
  }
  notify { 'Finished Installing IIS': }
}

class serviceW3SVC {
  require installIIS
  notify { 'Setting serviceW3SVC': }
  service { 'W3SVC':
    ensure => 'running',
    enable => 'true',
  }
  notify { 'Finished Setting serviceW3SVC': }
}

class stopDefaultWebsite
{
  require serviceW3SVC
  notify { 'Stopping Default Web Site': }
  iis::manage_site_state { 'Default Web Site':
    ensure    => 'stopped',
    site_name => 'Default Web Site'
  }
  notify { 'Finished Stopping Default Web Site': }
}

class includecoreandiis
{
  contain dotNetCore
  contain installIIS
  contain serviceW3SVC
  contain stopDefaultWebsite
}
```

On the agent node, i am getting dependency error in the event viewer:

```
Failed to apply catalog: Parameter provider failed on Exec[add-feature-NET-Framework-Core]: Invalid exec provider 'powershell' at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/modules/windowsfeature/manifests/init.pp:111
Wrapped exception:
Invalid exec provider 'powershell'
```

After restarting the `Puppet Agent` service on the client node couple of times, it fetches the rest of the files and it works.

How do i make it wait for all the required files to be downloaded before installing the mentioned windows features?

Comment: Never used puppet for windows, so I cannot make complete answer. But the key for successful deploy in such cases are 'require' blocks. You tell that some resource is requiring some other resource to be present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the PowerShell provider module.

Additionally you may want to look at the windowsfeature module and anything that is available in the puppetlabs/windows module pack.

Sounds like a plugin sync issue after rereading, plus waiting for a suitable provider.

Comment: the problem was the agent version.

Comment: Ah right on. Sorry for the short answer originally. Wanted to get you something you could work with.